# unable to access google places api after passing next page token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, https, google-places-api

hi i'm trying to access the belo url using nodejs client

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=12.8441975,80.223766&radius=500&types=restaurant&key=Afghghghghghg&pagetoken=dghdghghgdhghgh

i'm using a normal https client code to access . When i hit the url without passing page token it is working fine.But wheni pass that i'm getting the error as below

> INVALID REQUEST

Dont know where i am going wrong.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How much time passes between the two requests?  I've found that as much as a two second delay before the `pagetoken` request can be necessary.

> There is a short delay between when a next_page_token is issued, and when it will become valid. Requesting the next page before it is available will return an INVALID_REQUEST response. Retrying the request with the same next_page_token will return the next page of results.

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search#PlaceSearchPaging

Comment: A bit late but thank you so much for that. I've been scratching my head for days as the link was obviously working when I was clicking on it but no way to get it via requests ! Thank you so much again !